# ¿Cómo manejar correctamente múltiples excepciones de error de conexión en Python3? relacionado con la librería python-binance

Tags: python-3.x, socket, excepciones, python-requests, binance

Estoy desarrollando un tracker de criptomonedas usando la librería `python-binance` version `1.0.16` (última versión al día de hoy)

Mi problema aparece en una parte específica del proceso la cual es el login al server de Binance a través del `Client` usando las **api y secret keys**. Aquí está el código para eso:

```
from binance.Client import Client

api = input("Pega tu API KEY aquí: ")
secret = input("Ahora pega tu SECRET KEY aquí: ")

client = Client(api_key=api, api_secret=secret, tld = "com")
```

*Nota: Siempre que el usuario tenga una conexión a internet estable, ninguna excepción es devuelta, permitiendo al tracker trabajar como debería*

Sin embargo, sí por alguna razón el usuario no estuviese conectado a internet (sin que el lo supiera), las siguientes excepciones son devueltas después de ejecutar el código de arriba:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 72, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\socket.py", line 955, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):

gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1042, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 358, in connect
    self.sock = conn = self._new_conn()

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(

NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000020B4CEB4A00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.binance.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v3/ping (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000020B4CEB4A00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "c:\users\user\.spyder-py3\btcusdt_only-signals.system.py", line 207, in <module>
    client = Client(api_key= api_key, api_secret= secret_key, tld= "com")

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 300, in __init__
    self.ping()

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 526, in ping
    return self._get('ping', version=self.PRIVATE_API_VERSION)

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 371, in _get
    return self._request_api('get', path, signed, version, **kwargs)

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 334, in _request_api
    return self._request(method, uri, signed, **kwargs)

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 314, in _request
    self.response = getattr(self.session, method)(uri, **kwargs)

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 600, in get
    return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 565, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.binance.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v3/ping (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000020B4CEB4A00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

En resumen, hay 4 excepciones que necesitan ser manejadas:

- `gaierror`
- `NewConnectionError`
- `MaxRetryError`
- `ConnectionError`

Al principio intenté crear una alternativa según [esta otra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4844933/16467154) porque pensé que como la excepción `gaierror` era siempre la primera en ser devuelta, *Yo supuse* que al manejarla correctamente, el resto de las excepciones no serían devueltas, esto fue lo que hice:

```
from binance.Client import Client
import socket

api = input("Pega tu API KEY aquí: ")
secret = input("Ahora pega tu SECRET KEY aquí: ")

while True:
    try: 
        client = Client(api_key= api_key, api_secret= secret_key, tld= "com")
        break
    except socket.gaierror:
        print("No estás conectado a internet, primero asegúrate de estar conectado antes de ejecutar este programa")
        input("Una vez hecho, presiona le tecla Enter:")
```

Sin embargo, mi alternativa no manejó nada y terminó devolviendo exactamente la misma salida descrita arriba, con las mismas excepciones devueltas en el mismo orden.

Pero, **¡esta otra SÍ FUNCIONÓ**!:

```
from binance.Client import Client
import socket

api = input("Paste your API KEY here: ")
secret = input("Now paste your SECRET KEY here: ")

while True:
    try: 
        client = Client(api_key= api_key, api_secret= secret_key, tld= "com")
        break
    except Exception:
        print("No estás conectado a internet, primero asegúrate de estar conectado antes de ejecutar este programa")
        input("Una vez hecho, presiona le tecla Enter:")
```

Entonces, yo vine aquí para saber ¿sí hay una mejor forma que sólamente poner `except Exception` para manejar las 4 excepciones devueltas? es decir, no luce muy `Buenas Prácticas` para mi, y tampoco me permite saber exactamente qué está pasando y cómo puedo explicarle al usuario porque tal cosa está pasando, así que, ¿me pueden dar una mano?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo que puedes hacer para saber el tipo de excepción que te devuelve y poder procesarla adecuadamente es saber su nombre y los argumentos que tiene.

Por ejemplo con este código que no tiene declarada `x`:

```
try:
  print(x)
except Exception as e:
  print("Una excepción:", type(e).__name__, e.args)
```

Esto devolverá:

```
Una excepción: NameError ("name 'x' is not defined",)
```

Entonces podemos ver que la excepción correcta para procesar este error sería `NameError`

Una vez identificando el tipo de excepción que aparece podrás crear mensajes y/o acciones adecuadas para cada caso.

También podrías utilizar [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) y/o [`post_mortem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdb.post_mortem) de la librería `pdb` para guardar los mensajes en un `logger` (Con logging) o revisar a detalle lo sucedido (Con `post_mortem`).

Comment: Messirve, muchas gracias.